# Build source code to executable file for windows

Tags: openssl, windows-installer

How to compile and build source code to executable or MSI file so to install on Windows? I am required to build source code, https://github.com/openssl/openssl, to executable. can someone give me some tips on how to do it

Comment: Instructions for building on Windows are under the “build and install” section in the readme you linked to.

Comment: @prieber, I tried and I am able to install on my windows PC, but i would like to know if there is any ways to build & compile as executable or msi file? I would like to install on other computers also, without the need to install mingw64 or VS build tools on all other computers. is there a way I can do it? Appreciate your help

Comment: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries